# How to add points to points in polygon function

Tags: qgis

I have downloaded my shapefile and also a CSV file with the population of each location. Each population is associated to a meshblock (district) that has coordinates. I need to put this population onto a map but I can't seem to make these population's into points.

I tried using points in polygon function, but the drop down has no points to select from?

Comment: Did you try adding your csv as a point layer from the menubar: `Layer > Add Layer > Add Delimited Text Layer...`?

Comment: Yes thats the only way iv been adding my csv files. I was wondering maybe because my CSV file doesnt have any coordinates to them, only my shapefile does.

Comment: My CSV file has the same meshblocks as my shape file and i have joined these two as well, so thought my csv file would coordinates so im not sure where iv gone wrong

Comment: If the answer from the suggested post (of which your question seems to be a duplicate of) does not solve your problem, I would suggest [editing](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/198138/edit) your question to include specific details of the steps you have tried and where exactly you need help. Then this question can be re-opened =)